# $conexion->real_escape_string() o mysql_real_escape_string()?

Tags: php, mysql

estoy haciendo un login, y en mi php, para escapar caracteres no se si es recomendable hacer con `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

```
<?php
session_start();
$conexion = new mysqli("localhost","username","password","DB");
if (!$conexion) {
    die("Error al conectar con la base de datos ".$conexion->conect_error);
}
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM login";
$resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
if($resultado->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
        $usuario = $_POST['texto_login'];
        $usuario1 = mysql_real_scape_string($usuario,$conexion);
        $contrasena = $_POST['contrasena_login'];
        $contrasena1 = mysql_real_scape_string($contrasena,$conexion);
        $contrasena_sha = hash("sha512", $contrasena1);
        if ($usuario == $row['Usuario'] && $contrasena_sha == $row['Contrasena']) {
            $_SESSION = $usuario;
            echo "ok";
        }           
    }
}
$conexion->close();
?>
```

o

`$conexion ->real_escape_string()`

```
<?php
session_start();
$conexion = new mysqli("localhost","username","password","DB");
if (!$conexion) {
    die("Error al conectar con la base de datos ".$conexion->conect_error);
}
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM login";
$resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
if($resultado->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
        $usuario = $_POST['texto_login'];
        $usuario1 = $conexion->real_escape_string($usuario);
        $contrasena = $_POST['contrasena_login'];
        $contrasena1 = $conexion->real_escape_string($contrasena);
        $contrasena_sha = hash("sha512", $contrasena1);
        if ($usuario == $row['Usuario'] && $contrasena_sha == $row['Contrasena']) {
            $_SESSION = $usuario;
            echo "ok";
        }           
    }
}
$conexion->close();
?>
```

En realidad, no se cual utilizar, ya que la pagina oficial de PHP, dice que el ´mysql_real_escape_string()´ las versiones anteriores 5.5.0 y 7.0.0, y en realidad, yo utilizo el mysql y me va bien, es decir, me protege de las inyecciones sql básicas. Además en mi caso utilizo mysqli para conexion a la base de datos.

Comment: Realmente no veo de qué hay que *escapar* aquí  ¿?  Cuando tengas que protegerte de inyección SQL, la cual no es posible en una consulta como esta: `SELECT * FROM login`, considera usar consultas preparadas. Durante mucho tiempo se difundió el mito de que las funciones de escape era suficientes para proteger contra inyección, pero la experiencia demuestra que no (hay varios casos de inyección que se saltan la limpieza que estas funciones deberían hacer). Quizá sean casos aislados, pero, cuando una puerta está abierta, por recóndita que sea, algún día alguien puede entrar.

Comment: A parte de lo comentado por el compañero `mysql_real_scape_string` esta obsoleto y a sido eliminado en PHP7 en general toda la librería `mysql_*` se declaró obsoleta desde hace años y no se debería utilizar. En cualquier caso para evitar inyección el mejor camino son consulta preparadas, y una vez más como indica el compañero en tu consulta no hay nada que escapar.

Comment: Ok, lo mirare, gracias